# How to install older version on PostgreSQL and PHP5?

Tags: 10.04, apt, php, postgresql

Because of differencies in package versions between my development machine and my provider's server, I have to downgrade packages installed on my computer.
In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS default PostgreSQL version is 8.4, but I need 8.3. When I try to install postgresql-8.3 I get error:

> Package postgresql-8.3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package postgresql-8.3 has no installation candidate

So, my first question is: How do I install PostgreSQL 8.3 in Ubuntu 10.04.

And the second question: how do I install PHP 5.2.6, or at least 5.2 in Ubuntu 10.04 (where default version is 5.3.2)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to keep your development and production environments in sync, you may want to consider just using a virtual machine of some kind. That way you can make it EXACTLY like production, without needing to screw up anything on your workstation.

That being said, though, you might try [checkinstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org/). I've never used it, but the idea is to grab the sources of the version you want, configure and compile them as usual, and then use the program to make a DEB package to install.

There's also the idea of grabbing the source package from your server environment's version, and recompiling it on your machine with `debuild -us -uc -b`.

Answer (score 0):

If the old version of PostgreSQL is not available in Ubuntu repositories see [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/):

> This repository will integrate with your normal systems and patch management, and provide automatic updates for all supported versions of PostgreSQL throughout the support [lifetime](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) of PostgreSQL.

I don't know PHP.