# How do i install postgresql-8.3?

Tags: postgresql

I get

```
> sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-8.3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-8.3' has no installation candidate
```

I need v8.3 to match my production server (Heroku). Thanks!

Comment: In oneiric isn't available this version: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/33931/ and http://askubuntu.com/q/149304/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last version of ubuntu that packaged postgressql 8.3 was Hardy Heron 8.04 LTS. It is supported until April 2013 on the server if your interested in using it. Barring that, you can install the debs from here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy-updates/postgresql-8.3

You will need to grab the dependencies as well and manually install them in order. You won't get any security updates and it may just flat out fail to work :-( The alternative of adding the hardy repo to your sources.list is possible, but not for the feint of heart. I highly suggest upgrading if at all possible, or running an LTS if stability and unchanging packages is important.