# How do I install older PostgreSQL (8.4) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: postgresql

Well, it's the whole question. I installed 9.1 before, but I need older version now and I haven't yet found out how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4
```

Seems to do the trick (well, not really a trick).

Comment: `E: Package 'postgresql-8.4' has no installation candidate` says my Ubuntu 13.04(06.18.2013)

Answer (score 3):

If the old version of PostgreSQL is not available in Ubuntu repositories see [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/):

> This repository will integrate with your normal systems and patch management, and provide automatic updates for all supported versions of PostgreSQL throughout the support [lifetime](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install PostgreSQL 8.4 in ubuntu in specific version like ubuntu 12 then Follow the steps:

- Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list, and add a line for the repository :

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main"> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

- Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists :
  `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
  sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4`

Answer (score 0):

It's 2019 and (at least with my actual Ubuntu 16 config) PG versions prior to 9.3 are not available to instal with `apt-get`. I've followed the instructions provided in this [site](https://erpnani.blogspot.com/2016/03/install-postgresql-84-from-its-official.html) and now I have PG 10.10 and 8.4 installed. Required steps are (extracted from the previous link):

**1**. Create and edit the PostgreSQL repository by running the command below:

`~$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

Press I on keyboard and add the below line into the file:

`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`

Press Esc on keyboard and followed by :wq to save the file.

**2**. Download & import the repository key:

`~$ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

**3**. Update your system:

`~$ sudo apt-get update`

**4**. Now you’re able to install PostgreSQL via below command:

`~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4 pgadmin3`

**NOTE**: I've omitted pgadmin3 because I had it installed before.

**NOTE 2**: The link doesn't mention but if you have another PG version installed, remember you'll have to change port in one of your installations:

```
~$ sudo updatedb
~$ locate postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf
~$ cp /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf_yyyymmdd
~$ sudo vi /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Find the entry that says:
`port = 5433` and change port number to new value. Save file (:wq) and restart your postgres.